# run time error in displaying a vector(c++)

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having trouble displaying a vector in c++, my syntax seems to match the examples i've seen but program crashes and gives the 11db message in my console. I am creating a program that asks for input and unit types and then stores those, and gives various sample statistics based on the data entered, the breakpoint in my program is specifically on the line:

```
for(int i=0;i<totalMeters.size();i++)
```

the entire program is here, and I have successfully run it with all features except the vector printing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
double number1=100000;
double number2=-100000;
double howClose;
double newnum;
double sum=0;
double numberOfValues=0;
string unit;
string number1Unit;
string number2Unit;
double waitingNum;
vector <double> totalMeters;
void unitizer()
{
    while(cin>>newnum)
    {
        cout<<"what is the unit?(cm,m,in,ft)"<<endl;
        cin>>unit;
        if(unit!="ft"&&unit!="m"&&unit!="in"&&unit!="cm")
        {
            cout<<"incorect input"<<endl;
            unitizer();
        }
        cout<<newnum<<endl;
        if(newnum<number1)
        {
            number1=newnum;
            number1Unit=unit;
        }
        if(newnum>number2)
        {
            number2=newnum;
            number2Unit=unit;
        }
        sum+=newnum;
        numberOfValues++;
        cout<<"the smallest value so far is "<<number1<<number1Unit<<".";
        cout<<"the largest value so far is "<<number2<<number2Unit<<".";




        if(number1==number2)
        {
            cout<<number1<<number1Unit<<" is equal to "<<number2<<number2Unit<<endl;
        }

        if (unit=="cm")
            waitingNum=newnum/100;
        if (unit=="in")
            waitingNum=newnum*.0254;
        if (unit=="ft")
            waitingNum=newnum*.3048;
        if (unit=="m")
            waitingNum=newnum;
        totalMeters.push_back(waitingNum);


        howClose=abs(number1-number2);
        cout<<"The difference between the two values is "<<howClose<<"."<<endl;
        if(howClose<.001)
            cout<<"Wow, that's close"<<endl;

        cout<<"input one number please.(enter a non number to end the program.)"<<endl;
    }
}

void finalResults()
{
    cout<<"The sum of all the values is "<<sum<<"."<<endl;
    cout<<"the number of values enters is "<<numberOfValues<<"."<<endl;


}


void vectorOutput()
{
    for(int i=0;i<totalMeters.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<totalMeters[i]<<endl;

    }



}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cout<<"input one number please."<<endl;
    unitizer();
    finalResults();
    vectorOutput();
    return 0;
}
```

p.s. I tried to look at the actual function that was being called, but found it very long and above my current comprehension of the language.

Comment: `const char * argv[]` This is not standard C++. You shouldn't use global variables and use better names or comments as it's hard to understand your logic without effort.

Comment: A recursive function is not necessary. It is lucky that you have all those global variables, normally considered bad programming.

Comment: I know that. It really was a bad idea, my idea was to make them global first as I was learning new tools and then once I understood the syntax of the tool place them more appropriately, and I guess I was just in a hurry to get it running, probably a bit over excited. how would you recommend I replace the recursive function and return to the top of the program and not risk attempting to access variables that are not initialized? thank you for the comment though.

Comment: Thank you. taking out the addition arguments in the main function helped, although I really don't know why, I'm sorry that my names were not self evident and that I did not comment my code well. I was prone to egocentrism, and for that moment assumed that since I understood it everyone else would too, thank you for your patience and advice. I am sorry that I wasted your time, and made this code artificially ugly.

Answer (score 0):

const char * argv[] This is not standard C++. You shouldn't use global variables and use better names or comments as it's hard to understand your logic without effort. –  Neil Kirk

simply taking out the additional augments seemed to fix the problems